# what does the System class represent in java?

Tags: java

I do not know what does the System class represent in java.what is the meaning of system and is it like a console ,or somehow has a connection to a console ??

Comment: Please follow the guidelines here  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.System` class doesn't represent anything, really.  It is a class that comprises a bunch of `static` methods and three `static` fields.  Basically, it is a "utility class" for methods for interacting with the host system.  It is worth browsing the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) to get a better understanding of what it is in the `System` "grab bag"

The static fields contain references to the application's "standard input", "standard output" and "standard error" streams.  These *may be* connected to the console, or they may be connected to other sources / sinks for character data.  For example, if you run a java app like this:

```
  java com.example.MyApp < input.txt
```

then the standard input stream (in `System.in`) will read from the "input.txt" file rather than the console.

From the OO-design perspective, it is a poor example: IMO, a mistake.  However, the class has a very long history, and it is so embedded into common usage that correcting this design mistake is impossible.  In fact, it would have been impossible to correct the mistake even in Java 1.1 ... because the fixes would have broken backwards compatibility in a big way.

Comment: It *does* represent *something* : the JVM itself.  The JVM has a system clock one can inquire but not alter, it has available memory and the like, etc. etc.  Why is it "an error from the OO perspective" (a) to have a single instance (the instance is the Class<java.lang.System> object) of some class represent the single JVM and the state it is in (b) say, not to expose setter methods for stuff that *should* not be alterable in the first place ?

Comment: Sorry, but the javadoc doesn't agree with that.  Also, if `System` *represented* the system, then most of the methods would be instance methods, and it would be a singleton class.  Indeed, there are contexts where it would be useful if it wasn't a singleton.  And it would be better if there were regular getters and setters for the in/out/err streams rather the current odd design where you can change the "final" variables.  Then there's the infamous `arraycopy` method.

Comment: @StephenC it is interesting that the Runtime is a Singleton but System is a utility class. System.gc() calls Runtime.getInstance().gc() and System.exit(n) calls Runtime.getRuntime().exit(n);

Comment: Yes, it is interesting. And inconsistent. And (IMO) supports my assertion that `System` is an example of poor design.  My guess is that it is much older than Java 1.0 (!).  It was probably known to be a problem, but it was too hard to fix.  (There would be implications for JVM bootstrapping, etc.)  The `Runtime` class existed in 1.0, so my theory is that it was originally intended as a replacement for System, but they ran out of time in the "rush to market".